# Merge mode missing in Studio 3T import csv

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

Is there way to merge document during csv import . I dont find merge option in import csv in studio 3T

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've already contacted us at Studio 3T about this but perhaps this response might help others who have questions on this same concern. We replied:

"Studio 3T support overwriting documents with the same, existing id on import.
The requirement to merge documents would turn out to be far more complex than it might seem at first glance. Every merge would need to check for conflicts and resolve them in a predictable way. This task is not easy to automate.
We suggest building an aggregation pipeline with a $lookup stage if you simply want to join documents from one collections with documents from another collection:
docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup

I hope this helps!"

Comment: Thanks Studio 3T Team. But unfortunately our Requirement was to import multiple csv into single Collection. Kindly do consider merge option for future versions.

For those stuck with requirement like mine. They can avail momgoimport command line option and select mode as merge.